# JavaScript / jQuery - taking input from 2 drop down identical menus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 drop down lists, which both hold the same list of `teams`, one to be used as the `home` team and one as the `away` team. At the moment the first drop down list works, when a `team` is selected from the list, it's `id` and `name` is output to the page. But when the other drop down is clicked, nothing happens. So for example the output takes the id and team name and outputs them to the textboxes.

Here is an example of each drop down list and the relevant code below, can anyone help me out?

HTML generated for home team list:

```
<select id="teamList" style="width: 160px;">
<option></option>
<option id="1362174068837" value="1362174068837" class="teamDropDown">Liverpool</option></select>
```

HTML generated for away team list:

```
<select id="teamList" style="width: 160px;">
<option></option>
<option id="1362174068837" value="1362174068837" class="teamDropDown">Liverpool</option>
</select>
```

JADE template used to generate the HTML (used for both lists):

```
div#teamDropDownDiv
    -if(teamsList.length > 0){
        select#teamList(style='width: 160px;')
            option
                -each team in teamsList
                    option.teamDropDown(id="#{team.key}",value="#{team.key}") #{team.name}
```

JavaScript for the page:

```
 Team.initTeamsDD = function(){
  $("#teamList").change(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var teamId = $(this).val();

    $.get('/show/team/'+teamId, function(response){
      if(response.retStatus === 'success'){
        var teamData = response.teamData;
        $('#teamId').val(teamData.key);
        $('#teamName').val(teamData.name);
      } else if(response.retStatus === 'failure'){

      }
    });  
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two `<select>` elements both have the same "id" value, which is "teamList". You should never have two elements with the same "id". Because of this, the on-change event handler is getting attached to only one of them. You should change them to "homeTeamList" and "awayTeamList", and then use:

```
Team.initTeamsDD = function(){
  $("#homeTeamList, #awayTeamList").change(function(e){
...
```

Comment: I've now edited the `initTeamsDD` function as you suggested, and edited the template to make two different lists...an `away` list and a `home` list. The lists are both populated correctly but when I select either of them, none of them output the data.

Comment: @germainelol - No idea. I would have to see the modified code. Here is a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vyVVN/) showing the on-change handler working for two drop-down lists.